# Gradle Build failing with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm building an app which fetches data from Firebase adds it into an array adapter and displays it in a list view. When I try to build the app, it fails with:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
>    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

My Activity:

```
    package app.nert;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class display extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;
    private ArrayList<String> ttable = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-...");
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-...");
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        //Shared Preference declaration
        SharedPreferences sprefs = getSharedPreferences("nert.app", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String sid = sprefs.getString("school_id", "Not defined yet");//get schoolid
        String sch = sprefs.getString("school", "Not defined yet");//get schoolname
        String cl = sprefs.getString("class", "Not defined yet");// get classname
        String clid = sprefs.getString("class_id", "Not defined yet");//get classid
        TextView tod = findViewById(R.id.today);
        TextView tom = findViewById(R.id.tom);
        tod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Begin Shared Preferences
        SharedPreferences sprefs = getSharedPreferences("nert.app", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String sid = sprefs.getString("school_id", "Not defined yet");//get schoolid
        String sch = sprefs.getString("school", "Not defined yet");//get schoolname
        String cl = sprefs.getString("class", "Not defined yet");// get classname
        String clid = sprefs.getString("class_id", "Not defined yet");//get classid
        //End Shared Preferences

        //Begin get Day
        String weekDay;
        SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.US);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        weekDay = dayFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        String day = String.valueOf(weekDay);
        //End get Day
        ListView tday = findViewById(R.id.day);
        tday.setDividerHeight(0);

        final ArrayAdapter tdayadapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ttable);
        tday.setAdapter(tdayadapter);
        DatabaseReference gettt = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("schools").child("classes").child(sid).child(clid).child("timetable").child(day);
        gettt.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                tdayadapter.add(value);
                tdayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void homework(View view) {
        Intent hw = new Intent(this, homework.class);
        startActivity(hw);
    }

    public void replacement(View view) {
        Intent rp = new Intent(this, replacement.class);
        startActivity(rp);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    public void at(View view) {
        Intent an = new Intent(this, anifrom.class);
        startActivity(an);
    }

    public void today(View view) {
        ListView lstd = findViewById(R.id.day);
        ListView lstt = findViewById(R.id.tmo);
        TextView tod = findViewById(R.id.today);
        TextView tod2 = findViewById(R.id.today2);
        TextView tom = findViewById(R.id.tom);
        TextView tom2 = findViewById(R.id.tom2);
        lstt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tod2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tom2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lstd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void tom(View view) {
        ListView lstd = findViewById(R.id.day);
        ListView lstt = findViewById(R.id.tmo);
        TextView tod = findViewById(R.id.today);
        TextView tod2 = findViewById(R.id.today2);
        TextView tom = findViewById(R.id.tom);
        TextView tom2 = findViewById(R.id.tom2);
        lstd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tod.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lstt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tod2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tom2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

And my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.nert"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0-alpha"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
}


apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How can I prevent the build from failing?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yeah It's Just a bug in Android Studio, try `Build -> Clean Project`, and after that 
click `Build -> Rebuild Project`

Answer (score 2):

if your emulator is opening, just close it and try Build -> Clean Project, and after that click Build -> Rebuild Project